# If the largest number occurs more than once in the same list, how do I print them all out?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Here is my program,

```
empty_list = []
max_no = 0
for i in range(5):
    input_no = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    empty_list.append(input_no)
for x in empty_list:
    if x > max_no:
       max_no = x
high = empty_list.index(max_no)
print ([empty_list[high]])
```

Example list: `[4, 3, 6, 9, 9]`

Example output: `[9]`

How can I change my program to print out all the instances of the largest number occurring in the same list?

Expected output: `[9, 9]`

Comment: what do you mean by `print out all the largest numbers that occur more than once` what if you are given `[1,1,1,1,5]` ?

Comment: You want the answer (2, 9) or [9, 9]? (2, 9) will express that 9 appears 2 times

Comment: @taesu I would like to print out `[5]`.

Comment: @PascalFares `[9, 9]`. Basically all the instances of the largest number in the array.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the biggest number, you can use the Python built-in function `max()`

```py
max_no = max(empty_list)
```

In order to count them, you can use the `count()` method, like so:

```py
count_no = empty.count(max_no)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store both the maximum number and the number of occurrences of that number.

```
empty_list = []
max_no = 0
times = 0
for i in range(5):
    input_no = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    empty_list.append(input_no)
for x in empty_list:
    if x > max_no:
       max_no = x
       times = 1;
    elif x == max_no:
        times += 1
print([max_no] * times)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/kSBtd7)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You are asking, given a list with integers, you want a function that
returns a list with the largest integer N number of times where N is the
number of occurrence in the given list.

```
def foo(lst):
    r = max(lst) # find maximum integer in the list
    d = lst.count(r) # find how many times it occurs in the list
    return [r for i in range(d)] # create a list with the max int N number of times.
    
lst = [1,1,1,1,5,5,9]
print(foo(lst)) # prints [9]

lst = [1,1,1,1,5,5]
print(foo(lst)) # prints [5,5]

lst = [4, 3, 6, 9, 9]
print(foo(lst)) # prints [9,9]
```